# IIS 7.5 Rewrite help needed

Tags: iis, rewrite

I am trying to do something extremely straightforward.  I just need to force SSL and I am trying to use the URl Rewrite plugin.  I am getting no results when I put the following rule into my conf.

```
      <rewrite>

        <rules>

           <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
           <match url="(.*)[^/])$" />
            <conditions>
                    <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="443" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
             <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>

    </rewrite>
```

Any thoughts on why this isn't catching?

Comment: This pattern is wrong: `(.*)[^/])$` --  extra closing `)` (remove one of them) -- possibly that is the reason? BTW -- better check `{HTTPS}` = off instead of `{SERVER_PORT}` != 443, as you can easily run ssl on another (non-standard) port.

Comment: Thanks, I made that change but I am still not getting a redirect.

I just get HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Answer (score 2):

This is the rule that I have on a fully working site -- **works absolutely fine**. As you can see it is very close to what you have.

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

If it does not work for you -- then you have too look for something else (SSL is not configured at all/wrongly configured SSL etc). Dig into error details -- it should say:

- what file is not found **exactly**
- look at **error subcode** -- IIS 7.x has about 20 different subcodes -- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891 (e.g. "404.6 - Verb Denied" etc)